# Bootstrap Responsive Site in Browser, not Adapting in iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a fully responsive website based off of the Bootstrap framework. 
In the browser all the responsive features are working exactly as I want them to, however, it doesn't seem to be working on my iPhone. I'm still seeing a full size site.

Has anyone had this issue or would know what might be the cause?

Comment: Any code? We're not psychic.

Answer (score 13):

You almost certainly forgot the `<meta name="viewport">` tag the Bootstrap docs mention. In your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**edit:** Now that you've provided the URL, check out the syntax highlighting on this line:

```
<meta name="viewport' content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

You've opened with a double quote and closed with a single quote.

Comment: Well, I just checked and that code is in the header. Here is my header code:

Comment: Thank you so much! Glad to know it was an easy fix. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's important to specify `initial-scale` as the decimal `1.0` versus the integer `1`